# Activity opens external app that opens the activity thus doubling it in the activity stack

Tags: android, android-activity, twitter

I am trying to integrate Twitter in my app (Please read further even if you've never done this). This is the login workflow:

1. User clicks "Login with Twitter" in the activity
2. The Twitter authentication site comes up in the browser. User clicks Allow the app to use Twitter
3. Browser vanishes, activity opens again.

The problem is that the activity opens AGAIN, which means after clicking BACK I am still in this activity (right before logging in with Twitter) so I need to click BACK again.

This is the line that opens the Twitter authorization website in the browser:

```
SettingsActivity.this.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(requestToken.getAuthenticationURL())));
```

Putting `finish()` after it does not help.

Not even setting FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP:

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
  intent.setData(Uri.parse(requestToken.getAuthenticationURL()));
  intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
  startActivity(intent);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you set the activity's `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` in your manifest?

Also use this:

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```